# WebRTC doesn't generate ICE candidates for video in incoming video call for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, webrtc

I am developing an app for ios and have integrated WebRTC to make video calls. For outgoing call it's fine, all works fine. But when I want to receive a video call, while setting a local description, didGenerate delegate doesn't return me a ICE candidate for video call (candidate.sdpMid property should be 1) it returns me only ICE candidates for audio where candidate.spdMid is 0.

Here is the steps what I am doing:

- Upon receiving an incoming video call I am handling remoteSdp (a have all parameters with m=video), creating RTCSessionDescription with Offer
- After I am preparing media (adding video tracks to peerConnection)
- Setting remote description to peerConnection and in it's callback I am creating answerForConstraints where OfferToReceiveVideo and OfferToReceiveAudio are true.
- in answerForConstraints's callback I am setting localSdp from callback via setLocalDescription.
- Then Webrtc is generating ICE candidates and there is no candidates for video. usually ICE candidate should contain in property candidate.sdpMid = 1 for video, but I am getting candidate.sdpMid = 0 (only for audio).

**UPDATE:**

This is Remote SDP from server that I am receiving upon incoming video call:

> v=0 o=- 1707110628 1707110628 IN IP4 37.112.129.29 s=- c=IN IP4
> 37.112.129.29 t=0 0 a=msid-semantic:WMS AF60F46C a=extmap-allow-mixed a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 m=audio 11260 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 120 101 c=IN IP4
> 37.112.129.29 a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2 a=fmtp:120 maxaveragebitrate=40000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1 a=rtpmap:101
> telephone-event/8000 a=fmtp:101 0-15 a=fingerprint:SHA-256
> D6:D2:83:38:B0:55:47:0F:D4:C8:9F:A9:5E:43:C8:2C:3F:BF:35:4F:33:F7:F4:4B:BC:61:AC:9E:F6:A1:BD:9F
> a=setup:actpass a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
> a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
> a=extmap:3
> http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
> a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid a=mid:0
> a=ice-ufrag:zjnyg58k a=ice-pwd:5hvz1eniu8kx8j8gxxefx1 a=candidate:1 1
> UDP 2130706431 37.112.129.29 11260 typ host a=msid:AF60F46C
> ED29BB8139CB76CE5D3269A6CC875F7A a=rtcp-mux a=ssrc:1451091017
> cname:BD1D4D1615D5FFE3A434D305A24502B2-9 a=ssrc:1451091017
> msid:AF60F46C ED29BB8139CB76CE5D3269A6CC875F7A a=ptime:20 a=sendrecv
> a=silenceSupp:off - - - - m=video 11260 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 c=IN IP4
> 37.112.129.29 a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000 a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb a=rtcp-fb:96 nack a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli a=rtcp-fb:96
> transport-cc a=fingerprint:SHA-256
> D6:D2:83:38:B0:55:47:0F:D4:C8:9F:A9:5E:43:C8:2C:3F:BF:35:4F:33:F7:F4:4B:BC:61:AC:9E:F6:A1:BD:9F
> a=setup:actpass a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
> a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
> a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation a=extmap:3
> http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
> a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
> a=extmap:6
> http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-typea=extmap:7
> http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing a=extmap:8
> http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space a=extmap:4
> urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid a=extmap:10
> urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id a=extmap:11
> urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id a=mid:1
> a=ice-ufrag:zjnyg58k a=ice-pwd:5hvz1eniu8kx8j8gxxefx1 a=msid:AF60F46C
> 2AF282963F6E507FA3A87716A4B25F7B a=rtcp-mux a=ssrc:984206551
> cname:BD1D4D1615D5FFE3A434D305A24502B2-9 a=ssrc:984206551
> msid:AF60F46C 2AF282963F6E507FA3A87716A4B25F7B a=sendrecv

After I am initing RTCSessionDescription with offer type using sdp above:

```
- (void) onIncomingCallInvite:(NSString*)remotePhone remoteSdp:(NSString*)remoteSdp {
    RLogInfo(@"[tag = %@", self.localTag);
    self.isInviteReceived = YES;
    [self.terminateTimer invalidate];
    self.terminateTimer = nil;
    self.remoteMode = [ndSdpManager callModeFrom:remoteSdp];
    
    NSString *preparedRemoteSdp = [ndSdpManager prepareIncomingInviteSdp:remoteSdp];
    self.remoteDescription = [[RTCSessionDescription alloc] initWithType:RTCSdpTypeOffer sdp:preparedRemoteSdp];

    if (self.isIncomingAcceptedBeforeInvite) {
        self.isIncomingAcceptedBeforeInvite = NO;
        [self acceptCall:self.localModeIncomingAcceptedBeforeInvite];
    }
    
    [self.callViewDelegate didCallStateChanged];
    [self.libreProxy libre_progress_call:self.callId];
}

+ (NSString*) prepareRemoteSdp:(NSString*)existSdp{
NSString *target = [[self class] replaceAcap:existSdp];
target = [[self class] removeStringsContains:@"sha-1" existSdp:target];
target = [[self class] removeStringsContains:@"crypto" existSdp:target];
target = [[self class] addString:@"a=rtcp-mux" afterStringsContains:@"m=audio " existSdp:target];
RLogInfo(@"Prepare sdp from incoming invite = \n%@", target);
return target;
}

- (void) acceptCall:(ndCallMode)mode{
    RLogInfo(@"tag = %@", self.localTag);
    if ([self isEnded]){
        return;
    }
    if (!self.isInviteReceived) {
        self.isIncomingAcceptedBeforeInvite = YES;
        self.localModeIncomingAcceptedBeforeInvite = mode;
        return;
    }
    
    self.isAnswered = YES;
    self.localMode = mode;
    self.state = ndCallStateIncomingAnswer;
    
    [self.callManager showCallInterface:self];
    [self.callViewDelegate didCallStateChanged];
    
    [self prepare];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.peerConnection setRemoteDescription:self.remoteDescription
                            completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            if (error) {
                [strongSelf handleSetDescriptionError:error];
                return;
            }

            __weak typeof(self) weakSelf2 = strongSelf;
            [strongSelf.peerConnection answerForConstraints: 
[strongSelf defaultAnswerConstraints]
                                          
completionHandler:^(RTCSessionDescription *sdp,
                                                              
NSError *error){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf2 = 
weakSelf2;
                    if (error) {
                        [strongSelf2 
handleSetDescriptionError:error];
                        return;
                    }

                    strongSelf2.localDescription = 
[[RTCSessionDescription alloc] initWithType:RTCSdpTypeAnswer
                                                                                           
sdp:sdp.sdp];
                    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf3 = strongSelf2;
                    [strongSelf2.peerConnection 
setLocalDescription:sdp
                                                  
completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{
                            __strong typeof(self) strongSelf3 = 
weakSelf3;
                            if (error) {
                                [strongSelf3 
handleSetDescriptionError:error];
                            }
                        });
                    }];
                });
            }];
        });
    }];

    [self didConnected];
    [self doAcceptCall:mode];
}

- (void) doAcceptCall:(ndCallMode)mode{
RLogInfo(@"tag = %@", self.localTag);
if (!self.localDescription || ![self isLocalIceCandidateExist]) {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.acceptInviteRepeatTimer = [NSTimer 
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:
ND_ACCEPT_INVITE_CHECK_REPEAT_TIMEOUT
                                                                   
repeats:false
                                                                     
block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf doAcceptCall:mode];
    }];
    return;
}

NSString *preparedLocalSdp = [ndSdpManager 
addAudioIceCandidates:self.localAudioIceCandidates
                                              
videoIceCandidates:self.localVideoIceCandidates
                                                           
toSdp:self.localDescription.sdp];
preparedLocalSdp = [ndSdpManager 
prepareResponseSdpForIncomingInvite:preparedLocalSdp];

self.localSdp = preparedLocalSdp;
[self.libreProxy libre_accept_call:self.callId 
localSdp:self.localSdp];
}
```

the thing is that in didGenerate delegate I do not receive ICE candidates after setting remoteDescription, answer constraints and setLocalDescription and in doAcceptCall I cannot exit from timer, because isLocalIceCandidateExist returning NO because in didGenerate method ICE candidates for video have not been found and didn't added to array of localVideoIceCandidates. Here is how I am preparing media for call before setting descriptions.

```
- (void) prepare{
// Create peer connection.
RTCMediaConstraints *constraints = [self defaultPeerConnectionConstraints];
RTCConfiguration *config = [[RTCConfiguration alloc] init];
config.iceServers = self.callManager.iceServers;
config.bundlePolicy = RTCBundlePolicyMaxCompat;
config.disableIPV6OnWiFi = YES;
config.maxIPv6Networks = 0;
config.disableLinkLocalNetworks = YES;
config.sdpSemantics = RTCSdpSemanticsUnifiedPlan;

config.tcpCandidatePolicy = RTCTcpCandidatePolicyDisabled;
config.rtcpMuxPolicy = RTCRtcpMuxPolicyRequire;
config.continualGatheringPolicy = RTCContinualGatheringPolicyGatherContinually;
config.keyType = RTCEncryptionKeyTypeECDSA;

config.cryptoOptions = [RTCCryptoOptions alloc];
config.cryptoOptions.srtpEnableAes128Sha1_32CryptoCipher = FALSE;

self.peerConnection = [self.factory peerConnectionWithConfiguration:config constraints:constraints delegate:self];
    
// Create AV senders.
[self createMediaSenders];
} 

- (void) createMediaSenders{
self.stream = [self.factory mediaStreamWithStreamId:kMediaStreamId];

RTCMediaConstraints *constraints = [self defaultMediaAudioConstraints];
RTCAudioSource *audioSource = [self.factory audioSourceWithConstraints:constraints];
RTCAudioTrack *audioTrack = [self.factory audioTrackWithSource:audioSource trackId:kAudioTrackId];
NSMutableArray *streamIds = [@[kMediaStreamId] mutableCopy];
[self.stream addAudioTrack:audioTrack];

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
if (self.startMode == ndCallModeVideo){
    RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [self.factory videoSource];
    self.videoCapturer = [[VideoCapturer alloc] init];
    [self.videoCapturer startCaptureLocalVideoWithVideoSource:videoSource
                                                     settings:[LocalVideoCaptureSetting createDefaultSetting]];
    self.localVideoTrack = [self.factory videoTrackWithSource:videoSource
                                                      trackId:kVideoTrackId];
    [self.stream addVideoTrack:self.localVideoTrack];
    [self.localVideoTrack addRenderer:[self.callViewDelegate getCameraPreviewView]];
    
  
    [self.peerConnection addTrack:self.localVideoTrack streamIds:streamIds];
}
#endif

[self.peerConnection addTrack: audioTrack streamIds:streamIds];
}
```

This is constraints:

```
- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultPeerConnectionConstraints {
NSDictionary *mandatoryConstraints = nil;
if (self.startMode == ndCallModeAudio){
    mandatoryConstraints = @{
                             @"OfferToReceiveAudio" : @"true",
                             @"OfferToReceiveVideo" : @"false"
                             };
}
else{
    mandatoryConstraints = @{
                             @"OfferToReceiveAudio" : @"true",
                             @"OfferToReceiveVideo" : @"true"
                             };
}
NSDictionary *optionalConstraints = @{ @"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement" : @"true" };
RTCMediaConstraints* constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                                                                         optionalConstraints:optionalConstraints];
return constraints;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your SDP offer negotiates BUNDLE generating only candidates with sdpMid 0 is the expected and correct behavior as all m-lines in the BUNDLE group are going to use those candidates.

Comment: here is the BUNDLE
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
so 0 for audio and 1 for video